# Attach Maya to debug in VS Code 1.28.0

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, maya

I followed this tutorial to attach Maya in VS code : 
http://iwonderwhatjoeisworkingon.blogspot.com/2017/04/debugging-maya-using-visual-studio-code.html
But "secret", "remoteRoot" and "localRoot" are not allowed in launch.json
I tested several configurations, but nothing happens (bottom bar stays blue)
I'm new in vs code, so I certainly missed something.
Do you have any tips ?
Thanks,
Fabrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localRoot` and `remoteRoot` are allowed, they have just moved into the `pathMappings` setting since that blog post was written (see the [debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging)). And there is no need for a `secret` anymore.